# NSIS call dll function

Tags: nsis

Help me please. I have a little script:

```
*!include Library.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WordFunc.nsh
SetPluginUnload alwaysoff
Outfile "Impersonate.exe"



# create a default section.
Section
System::Call "wtsapi32::WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() i .r0" 
MessageBox MB_OK "Ative session: $0"// Here i got error in $0

 System::Call 'wtsapi32::WTSEnumerateSessionsA(i 0, i 0, i 1, *i .r0, *i .r1) i .r2'
${If} $2 != 0
    ${For} $R2 1 $1
        System::Call "*$0(i .r3, &t1024 .r4, i .r5)"
        DetailPrint "a = $0, $3, $4, $5"//Here i got spoild data
    ${Next}
    System::Call 'wtsapi32::WTSFreeMemory(i r0)'
${EndIf}
SetPluginUnload manual
System::Free 0
SectionEnd*
```

What is wrong in my script? And how enumerate data of struct type properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't mix A suffixed functions (WTSEnumerateSessions**A**) with the **t** string type. You should mention the NSIS version you are using and if you are targeting Ansi/Unicode, 32/64 bit when asking questions like these...

Answer (score 1):

WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId is actually in kernel32. pWinStationName in WTS_SESSION_INFO is a pointer to a string and you have to move a/the pointer in the loop to access subsequent items:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define WTS_CURRENT_SERVER 0
!if "${NSIS_PTR_SIZE}" <= 4
!define STRUCTSIZE_WTS_SESSION_INFO 12
!endif

Section
System::Call "KERNEL32::WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()i.r0" 
DetailPrint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId=$0

System::Call 'wtsapi32::WTSEnumerateSessions(i ${WTS_CURRENT_SERVER}, i 0, i 1, *i .r0, *i .r1)i.r2'
DetailPrint "WTSEnumerateSessions returned $2, count=$1"
${If} $2 <> 0
    StrCpy $R2 0
    ${DoWhile} $R2 U< $1
        IntOp $2 ${STRUCTSIZE_WTS_SESSION_INFO} * $R2
        !if "${NSIS_PTR_SIZE}" <= 4
        IntOp $2 $0 + $2
        !else
        !error TODO
        !endif
        System::Call "*$2(i .r3, t.r4, i .r5)"
        DetailPrint "#$R2 PWTS_SESSION_INFO@$2: sess=$3, winsta=$4, state=$5"
        IntOp $R2 $R2 + 1
    ${Loop}
    System::Call 'wtsapi32::WTSFreeMemory(i r0)'
${EndIf}
System::Free 0
SectionEnd
```

Comment: @VladSchegolev If it solved your problem then you should accept it as the answer...